# Является ли данная функция примером итеративного процесса?

Tags: javascript

```js
const getRepeat = (str, count) => {
  if (count === 1) {
    return str;
  }
  const iter = (counter, acc) => {
    if (acc === 1) {
      return counter;
    }
    return iter(counter + str, acc - 1);

    return;
  };

  return iter(str, count);
};

console.log(getRepeat("hi", 5));
```

Comment: скорее примером рекурсивного вызова, а не итерационного

Comment: Да, данная функция является примером итеративного процесса.

Comment: @Zhihar, здесь речь не про вызовы.

Comment: Я вижу [хвостовую рекурсию](https://ru.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Хвостовая_рекурсия). Заметьте разницу между «итерационный» и «итеративный». В последнем случае, люди, которые придумали это определение, подразумевают соответствующее поведение компилятора при оптимизации. Поправьте, если не прав.

Comment: _In general, an iterative process is one whose state can be summarized by a fixed number of state variables, together with a fixed rule that describes how the state variables should be updated as the process moves from state to state and an (optional) end test that specifies conditions under which the process should terminate_

Comment: Да, в своё время правильно перевели определение из SICP именно как «итеративный». Потому что итерационный процесс выполнения инструкций в общем понимании - это цикл. Код выше станет поистине итерационным, если сработает оптимизация хвостовой рекурсии (TCO). Можно проверить вызовом с count = 0. А так, имхо, это бесполезная характеристика до тех пор, пока вопрос не будет уточнён.